# R - extract part of xml with condition

Tags: r, xml

I have this dataframe. What I'm looking for is to extract id value od provider **if name is goldman**. Please notice that in some rows is no goldnam provider so result should be NA.

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    xml = c(
      as.character(
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
          <response>
            <provider name=\"bank_of_ammerica\">
                <success>true</success>
                <id>12</id>
            </provider>
            <provider name=\"goldman\">
                <success>true</success>
                <id>13</id>
            </provider>
          </response>",
        
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
          <response>
            <provider name=\"bank_of_ammerica\">
                <success>true</success>
                <id>12</id>
            </provider>
            <provider name=\"goldman\">
                <success>true</success>
                <id>16</id>
            </provider>
          </response>",
        
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
          <response>
            <provider name=\"bank_of_ammerica\">
                <success>true</success>
                <id>12</id>
            </provider>
          </response>"
      )
    )
  )
```

So result should be

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1:3),
    id_val = c(13, 16, NA_integer_)
  )
```

Comment: why is each id tag not closed? is this a valid xml? ie there is no `</id>`

Comment: My bad, sorry. Now its correct

Comment: Hey you cannot get the desired output. You need to edit the question again. eg the 2nd element has 13 on id and not 16

Comment: I have extended the description, I'm looking for only providers where provider name="goldman". bank_of_ammerica (or others) should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aha. Remove the command `as.character`. it messes with everything.

Anyway. You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
df%>%
  mutate(id_Val = map_chr(xml,~as_xml_document(.x)%>%
               html_node("provider[name=goldman] id")%>%
               html_text()))%>%
  select(-xml)

  id id_Val
1  1     13
2  2     16
3  3   <NA>
```